# Tab characters in OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I'm using OpenXML to add text to a pargraph node. I am wrapping OpenXML methods, and have the following method to append text, which works fine with text without markup.

```
    public void AddPlainParagraphText(string text)
    {
        m_wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(
            new Paragraph(
                new Run(
                    new Text(text))));
    }
```

I know that for special characters such as tabs, you need to use OpenXML's [TabChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tabchar.aspx) class and append that to the Text item. I'm trying to figure out if I can have this automated, where OpenXML would see the '\t' in the text, and automatically set the XML up to support the tab via . I suppose I could tokenize the string by \t, but then I'd have to search for every type of markup character. Can this be done automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split them up on receiving the text and add then on every '\t'

```
var stringArray = text.Split('\t');

var paragraph = new Paragraph();

for(var i = 0; i <= stringArray.Length; i++)
{
    paragraph.Append(new Run(new Text(stringArray[i])));

    if(i != stringArray.Length)
       paragraph.Append(new Run(new TabChar()));
}

m_wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(paragraph);
```

**Edit after comment : Indeed they should be put into `Run`s**

Comment: I see an off by one in the instruction `paragraph.Append(new Run(new Text(stringArray[i])));`